# kendo-dropdowntree Angular - Select child node only

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am working an angular view using kendo-dropdowntree, and I want to restrict users from selecting a parent node, i.e. allow child-node/leaf selection only. below is my current implementation.

1. (close) = $event.preventDefault(); // This prevents dropdown tree from closing.
2. on value change event, I check if node has some children, then do nothing. if there is no child then select this node and close dropdown. However if user wants to close it by selecting same value, value change event is not fired and user is forced to select a different node.

Alternatively, I tried to select first child of the parent, but updating value is not reflected on the control and continue to show previously selected node.

Solution to any of these problems will help me resolve this issue. I found select event of kendo-dropdowntree in Javascript but there is no such event in Angular.